# Creating a popup menu in a fragment android

Tags: android, fragment, fatal-error, popupmenu

I am trying to create a popup menu in a fragment with a dynamic overlay. I have a video playing in a fragment, and when you touch the screen an overlay gets created with button controls. One of the button controls is going to create a popup menu when it's pressed.

```
@Override
// when we touch the screen
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    Log.v(TAG, "onTouch() ");
    if (mMediaControl == null) {
        createMediaController();
        mMediaControl.show();
        return true;
    }
    mMediaControl.show();
    return false;
}


private void createMediaController() {
    Log.i(TAG, "createMediaController()");

    destroyMediaController();

    // create media controller
    mMediaControl = new MediaController(getActivity(), false);
    // set media player as this.
    mMediaControl.setMediaPlayer(this);
    mMediaControl.setAnchorView(mSurfaceView);


    mMediaControl.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    View v = makeControllerView(mMediaControl);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    mMediaControl.addView(v, frameParams);
    mMediaControl.show();
}

private View makeControllerView(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v= inflate.inflate(R.layout.custom_media_controller, null);
    final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)   v.findViewById(R.id.imageId);

    imageButton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
             v.post(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     showPopupMenu(v);
                 }
             });
        }
    });



    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(show_popup)
private void showPopupMenu(View view) {

    // Create a PopupMenu, giving it the clicked view for an anchor
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), view);

    // Inflate our menu resource into the PopupMenu's Menu
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());

    // Set a listener so we are notified if a menu item is clicked
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new     PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
          // whatever  
          return true;
        }
    });

    popup.show();
}
```

This is almost directly out of the android doc example of popup menus.

Whenever I press the button to create the menu, I get this fatal exception.

> 10-16 12:17:55.554    2974-2974/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: ia.android.com, PID: 2974
>       android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41efd798 is not valid; is your activity running?
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:582)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:76)
>               at amazon.view.AmazonWindowManagerImpl.addView(AmazonWindowManagerImpl.java:83)
>               at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1063)
>               at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:969)
>               at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:654)
>               at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:167)
>               at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:132)
>               at android.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:170)
>               at ia.android.com.PlayerActivity$PlayerFragment.showPopupMenu(PlayerActivity.java:347)
>               at ia.android.com.PlayerActivity$PlayerFragment.access$700(PlayerActivity.java:143)
>               at ia.android.com.PlayerActivity$PlayerFragment$11$1.run(PlayerActivity.java:473)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:755)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5266)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:826)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:642)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: `is not valid; is your activity running? at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:582) at` ?

Comment: Check in your stack weather you have an earlier exception, which might caused your app to crash before the attempt to add the popup

Comment: The app crashes at popup.show() everytime. I think it's directly related, because I can touch the screen and press other buttons, just not the one that creates the popup.

Comment: Did you check your stack trace for other exceptions?

Comment: @UdiIdan I'm not familiar with the process of checking the stack trace. But I do have this:

`W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: 
 com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@425fba30 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@426b19d0


W/WindowManager﹕ Attempted to add window with token that is a sub-window: aborting.`

Comment: Check your LOGCAT view in Android Studio, you'll find it there

Comment: Going through the debugger, I found stackTraceElement array list. What am I looking for?

Comment: This is something that will help you a lot.
See here:
https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html#systemLogView

Comment: If going through the stack trace is looking through logcat (like what that link is suggesting), then yeah we're fine. I get the two warnings I get in the comment i sent you, and the fatal error in the original post are the only exceptions I have.

Comment: android.widget.PopupMenu